# PHP get the calling object on a method

Tags: php

Is there a way to get the actual calling object from a method?

For example, I have a scenario where I do something like this:

```
$user = new User;
$user->setName('name');
$user->save($user);
```

Instead of passing the $user to the save method, it would be nice to just have it get the calling object information.

I know I can do `get_called_class()` but that doesn't return the actual object's data.  I was also looking at PHP's Reflection classes but didn't see anything exactly right.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use `$this`? I'm sure you've used it in the `setName` method too.

Comment: Because I've over-complicated this in my brain.

Comment: Actually, to more accurately describe the thought process.  The User object, extends a Model object, which extends a Db object, which has the save() method.  By using $this within the Db object, I'm actually getting Db, Model, and User, when all I need is the User.  It doesn't really matter, but wasn't as clean as I was hoping.

Comment: "I'm actually getting Db, Model, and User, when all I need is the User" -> huh? if your user extends a model object and the model extends a db object, when you set up a new user you get a "package" of the three, you cannot extend your cake and not it eat it too. Passing $user would have the same effect as using $this in your save method as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your object (and thus from within the `save` function itself, you can utilize the `$this` keyword to access the object itself. Alternatively...

```
public static function getInstance() { 

  if(!self::$instance) { 
    self::$instance = new self(); 
  } 

  return self::$instance; 

}
```

Where `instance` would be a private member variable. Make sure your constructor is private so that your object cannot be instantiated externally. <--- all this assuming php5.

Comment: This is the singleton pattern. Does that actually help with the problem at hand?

Answer (score -2):

I think you can do self->save($this), if save is a class method, or just save($this) if save is an instance method.

Anyway, the point is $this refers to the current instance. So setName is acts on an instance of user, so $this should equal that user inside of setName.

Comment: `$this` doesn't exist where `$user->save()` is being called, so it makes no sense to call `$user->save($this)`.